# Rake asset routes for a rails project

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I may be wrong here, but routes are automatically generated for files in your public directory.

So if this was in your rails project

```
public/images/cat.jpg
```

You could literally type " public/images/cat.jpg " and it would appear in the browser. Is there anyway to rake routes and get these asset routes? Or they not actually roots? Do they work differently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are not actually routes, they are considered "static assets" and are simply served up as is.

From the Rails [asset pipeline documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#how-to-use-the-asset-pipeline):

> Any assets under public will be served as static files by the application or web server.

So in the end, there's nothing really special about them; they are merely served up. That's about it.

Also, the URL `www.example.com/public/images/cat.jpg` will not work, you'll need to ditch the `public` part, so that it appears like `www.example.com/images/cat.jpg`, or simply `/images/cat.jpg` if this is a link.

Answer (score 1):

```
#{RAILS_ROOT}/images/cat.jpg
```

That will do.